# Moving a div element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I'm trying to solve a problem where I have to move a div element within a div.

I found similar solutions to the problem on this site so I managed to solve the "moving part".

The problem is, that I want to be able to click on a div to choose which should be moved.

And finally make sure that you can't move a div to the position of another div.

My CSS:

```
.container { width: 450px; height: 450px; border: 1px #000 solid; position: relative; }

.box1 { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px #000 solid; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100px; background: #006699 }

.box2 { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px #000 solid; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100px; background: #33ccff }

.player { width: 50px; height: 100px; border: 1px #000 solid; position: absolute; right: 100px; top: 0px; background: red }
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.container').mousemove(function(e) {
  
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;     
      
      if(x < 400 & y < 400) {
          $('div.box1').css({'left': x});
          $('div.box1').css({'top' : y});
      }
  });
});
```

See my solutions on http://jsfiddle.net/cGZxv/162/

Comment: Have you looked at [jquery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)? It sounds like it might do what you're looking for, without having to hand-craft it all yourself.

Comment: `$('div.box1').css({'left': x, 'top' : y});`

Comment: This question is **way** too broad to ask someone else to do. The overlap detection and reaction is going to be non trivial. You can move one by clicking on it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cGZxv/166/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too broad to answer. But without the overlap detection:

Your code should be something like this: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/cGZxv/168/)**.

I recommend you to use **[jQueryUI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)** instead.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var clicked = false;
  var element;
  $('.container div').mousedown(function(){ clicked = true; element = $(this); });
  $('.container div').mouseup(function(){ clicked = false; });
  $('div.container').mousemove(function(e) {
      if(clicked == true)
      {
          var cW = $(this).width();
          var cH = $(this).height();
          var oW = element.width();
          var oH = element.height();
          var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - oW/2;
          var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop - oH/2;

          if(x < (cW-oW) && y < (cH-oH) && x > 0 && y > 0 ) 
          {
              element.css({'left': x, 'top' : y});
          }
      }
  });
});
```